# jQuery addClass to HTML Anchor ony work for first time

Tags: c#, jquery, append, bootstrap-modal

One of my website need to have a function which the flow is:
Button Click > Pop Modal > Close Modal

When people click the button, the button style will be change to loading with jQuery addClass until Modal Pop Up.

When Modal Pop Up, the button behind will be remove the loading class by jQuery.

When people close the Modal, they can click again on the button and call modal pop again.

I'm has been tried a lot of method but all method will have their own issue which I mention it below:

This is my button code (in iFrame)

```
<a runat="server" id="btnPersonalSearch" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onserverclick="btnPersonalSearch_ServerClick"  >
    <span runat="server" id="iconPersonalSearch" class="" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    Search
</a>
```

When people click the button above, the button class will be change with jQuery

```
$("#btnPersonalSearch").click(function () {
    $('#iconPersonalSearch').attr("class","spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-05");
});
```

When the modal pop, I use this code to remove the class to let it back to normal

```
$("#PersonalModal").on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#iconPersonalSearch').attr("class", "");
});
```

or this one

```
$("#PersonalModal").on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#iconPersonalSearch').removeClass('spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-05');
});
```

**Question 1:**
It is succesful to change the style to loading after I clicked the button, but when I close the modal and click again, the style will not have any changing again (but modal pop still work). May I know what problem caused this?

The modal pop after some calculation done from code behind with c#

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "$('#PersonalModal').modal('show');", true);
```

Actually, the best effect for this function should need to append modal to top window,
But when I append it to top window, the first click button can change the style and also pop modal, the second click on the button will become no function at all included style changing and modal pop.

I use the code below from code behind to append modal to top window

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "var fatherBody = $(window.top.document.body);fatherBody.append($('#PersonalModal').modal('show'));", true);
```

**Question 2:**
How can I let the button work with style changing and also modal pop no matter how many times I click it?

Comment: Check to see if the element id is not getting modified or changed. Are you getting any error in console window of browser ?

Comment: why are you making a full call to the server just to show a modal? That makes no sense really. Just show the modal directly using jQuery inside `$("#btnPersonalSearch").click(function () {` . If you need to do some server-side processing in order to populate the modal, it would be much better to use AJAX for that, then you don't have the problem of a full page refresh (which I'm fairly sure is probably causing, or at least not helping with, the issues you're describing).

Comment: Your class changes to `iconPersonalSearch` should not have any impact on how the button works.  I recommend using `$().addClass("class list with spaces")` and `$().removeClass("same class list with spaces")` - using `.attr("class"..` will remove any *other* classes not in the list of classes you're changing.  Either way, if you remove the add/remove class / attr("class") then you can be sure to eliminate that from your investigation.

Comment: @AmbrishPathak Doesn't have any related error appeared

Comment: @ADyson Yes, it has a lot calculation to be done before modal pop, however, the button is under UpdatePanel already to prevent full page refresh...

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes, I been tried to use .addClass and .removeClass already, the problem still same

Comment: UpdatePanels are nightmarish disaster of attempt to mould an AJAX implementation onto the WebForms page lifecycle (which itself was an awkward attempt to mould a desktop development pattern onto a stateless web application). Almost certainly better (and simpler to implement and understand) to use your own AJAX implementation (e.g. using fetch() or jQuery) and call a webmethod or little wcf data service within your application to do the calculations and send the result, and then you can display the modal once the result arrives back in the browser. That's how I'd do it, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve by using code below for addClass

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
if (prm != null) {
    prm.add_beginRequest(function (sender, e) {
        $('#iconPersonalSearch').addClass('spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-05');
    });
}
prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
    if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
        $('#iconPersonalSearch').attr("class", "");    
    }
});
```